# XwalkView crash , org.chromium.base.ApplicationStatus$ActivityInfo.getListeners() on a null object reference

Tags: android, crosswalk

I have a B Activity and XwalkView in it, then I start B from A activity and it crashed。log like this:

- Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '**org.chromium.base.ObserverList org.chromium.base.ApplicationStatus$ActivityInfo.getListeners()**' on a null object reference
- at org.xwalk.core.ReflectConstructor.newInstance(ReflectConstructor.java:54)
- at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.reflectionInit(XWalkView.java:1882)
- at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.(XWalkView.java:305)
- at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
- at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)

Comment: org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12

Answer (score 0):

finally  I found that  I set the setContentView() before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), the I swith this two line code ,it works。